# Render a buffer to screen use texture method behave weird in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, textures

I have trouble to render a buffer(eg,800*600*3 array) displaying in scrren. I have implemented scan line Z buffer algorithm in C++, after caculated the framebuffer data, I treat the framebuffer as a texture to wrap the display window, but the program behaves weird. My development platform is Ubuntu 16.04, use glfw and glad for OpenGL. I can not put all code here, part of them are as follow:

> **Main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

#include <glad/glad.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>

#include "camera.h"
#include "modelLoader.h"
#include "scanLineZBuffer.h"
#include "debug.h"

// settings
const unsigned int SCR_WIDTH = 800;
const unsigned int SCR_HEIGHT = 600;

// vertex shader
const char *vertexShaderSource =
"#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
"layout (location = 1) in vec2 aTexCoord;\n"
"out vec2 TexCoord;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   gl_Position = vec4(aPos, 1.0);\n"
"   TexCoord = aTexCoord;\n"
"}\0";

// fragment shader
const char *fragmentShaderSource = 
"#version 330 core\n"
"out vec4 FragColor;\n"
"in vec2 TexCoord;\n"
"uniform sampler2D Texture;\n"
"void main()\n"
"{\n"
"   FragColor = texture(Texture, TexCoord);\n"
"   //FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);\n"
"}\n\0";

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc <= 1) {
        std::cerr << "Usage: %" << argv[0] << " <input file>" << std::endl;
        exit(1);
    }

    GLFWwindow *window;

    if (!glfwInit()) {
       std::cerr << "GLFW init fail." << std::endl;
       return -1;
    }

    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

    // create window 800*600
    window = glfwCreateWindow(SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, "Z-Buffer demo", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window) {
       glfwTerminate();
       return -1;
    }
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    // init glad， load opengl func pointer
    if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glfwGetProcAddress)) {
       std::cout << "Failed to initialize GLAD" << std::endl;
       return -1;
    }

    // compile shader
    // ------------------------------------
    // vertex shader
    int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertexShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    // check compile error
    int success;
    char infoLog[512];
    glGetShaderiv(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::VERTEX::COMPILATION_FAILED\n"
          << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    // fragment shader
    int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragmentShader, 1, &fragmentShaderSource, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

    glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::FRAGMENT::COMPILATION_FAILED\n"
          << infoLog << std::endl;
    }

    // link shaders
    int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
    // check link error
    glGetProgramiv(shaderProgram, GL_LINK_STATUS, &success);
    if (!success) {
        glGetProgramInfoLog(shaderProgram, 512, NULL, infoLog);
        std::cout << "ERROR::SHADER::PROGRAM::LINKING_FAILED\n"
          << infoLog << std::endl;
    }
    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);

    // vetices information
    // put the texture on window.
    float vertices[] = {
      // pos              // vexture coord
      1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 1.0f,
      1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
     -1.0f,-1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 0.0f,
     -1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,  0.0f, 1.0f
    };

    // index 
    unsigned int indices[] = {  
      0, 1, 3, // first triangle
      1, 2, 3  // second triangle
    };

    // point to vexture data
    char *texture_data;

    unsigned int VBO, VAO, EBO;
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
    glGenBuffers(1, &EBO);

    glBindVertexArray(VAO);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices,GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, EBO);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(indices), indices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    // pos property
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float), (void *)0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    // vexture coord property
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 5 * sizeof(float),
                    (void *)(3 * sizeof(float)));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    // define vexture
    unsigned int texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glViewport(0, 0, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT);

    // update window
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {
       // render
       glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

       // update vexture data
       // color_test is a func to generate buffer data. please see the bottom
       texture_data = color_test(800, 600);

       // please notice this place.
       // send RGB texture data to gpu. @1
       glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture_data);

       // just send red value of texture data. @2
       //glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED, SCR_WIDTH, SCR_HEIGHT, 0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, texture_data);

       // the program works
       glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
       glBindVertexArray(VAO);
       glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);

       glfwSwapBuffers(window);
       glfwPollEvents();
   }

   glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
   glDeleteBuffers(1, &VBO);
   glDeleteBuffers(1, &EBO);

   glfwTerminate();

   return 0;
}
```

> **debug.h**

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

// the color_test func
char texture_data[800*600*3];
char* color_test(int width, int height) {
    std::srand(std::time(nullptr));
    // use rand() to generate RGB value.
    for (int i = 0; i < height; ++i){
        char c = rand()%256;
        // same RGB value every line.
        for (int j = 0; j < width; ++j){
            int index = i*width+j;
            texture_data[index] = c;
            texture_data[index + 1] = c;
            texture_data[index + 2] = c;
        }
    }
    return (char*)texture_data;
}
```

I hope the texture can occupy the total window space.
But...

**Use the @1 code, the result**
[image: wired output, occupy 1/3]
I don't know what happened.

**Use the @2 code, the result**
[image: behave well]
This one behave well.

So, Can someone tell me what happened ? And what should i do ?

Comment: Can You reformat the code to have the actual functions and how/where are they called (basically what You have in Your C++ source file)?

Comment: The statement `int index = i*width+j;` looks slightly odd.  Shouldn't it be `int index = 3*(i*width+j);` since you're creating a three channel RGB texture?  Although I could be miles off.

Comment: @Matso, Have done!

Comment: @G.M, You are absolutely right! Thanks very much!